# Aggregate rows with different order of naming

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregation

Let's say I have a table as follows:

```
df <- data.frame("interaction" = c("A_B","A_C","D_B","B_A", "C_A"), 
                 "value" = c(10,25,6,1,4))

  interaction value
1         A_B    10
2         A_C    25
3         D_B     6
4         B_A     1
5         C_A     4
```

I would like to add values that are referring to the same thing (for instance A_B and B_A are the same columns essentially). The results that I want would like so:

```
 interaction value
1         A_B    11
2         A_C    29
3         D_B     6
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: row 4 value for `B_A` should be 0 (and not 1) if we copy your `df` code.

Comment: Changed it. Thanks for noticing it and giving the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` library. Separate the `interaction` column in two separate columns by splitting on `"_"`, sort them and get the `sum` of `value` for each group.

You may then combine the two sorted columns again using `unite`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(interaction, c('col1', 'col2'), sep = '_') %>%
  group_by(group1 = pmin(col1, col2), group2 = pmax(col1, col2)) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  unite(interaction, group1, group2)
  

# interaction value
#  <chr>       <dbl>
#1 A_B            10
#2 A_C            29
#3 B_D             6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by the "_" character, `sort` the resulting split strings, and `sum` the `value`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(interaction = paste0(sort(str_split(interaction, "_", simplify = T)), collapse = "_")) %>% 
  group_by(interaction) %>%  
  summarize(value = sum(value))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  interaction value
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 A_B            10
2 A_C            29
3 B_D             6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `igraph`

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

df %>%
  separate(interaction, c("from", "to")) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  simplify(edge.attr.comb = "sum") %>%
  get.data.frame() %>%
  unite("interaction", from:to)
```

which gives

```
  interaction value
1         A_B    11
2         A_C    29
3         D_B     6
```